# How to create in eclipse android project with both modules mobile and wear?

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

Now I used last version `Eclipse` and `Android SDK`.

But can't find solution how todo as in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#CreateProject).

Also I don't know how to show in Graphical Layout screen of wear as [hear](https://developer.android.com/images/tools/wizard7.png). I'm select `Android Wear Square` and set `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme, but anyway see battery/wifi signal. If I select `Android Wear Round`, also anyway see square layout.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using ? Im using `0.8.12` and in File -> New Project i can easly select The "Regular" sdk for Phone and Tablets, and Wear

Comment: @forcewill, I'm use Eclipse. I want create project AS at Android Studio.

Comment: ah ok sry have no ideia in eclipse I stopped using it about 2 years ago, btw AndroidStudio is the official Android IDE now any particular reason for not using it?

Comment: Hm, I don't know why missed good topic: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html (Package Manually).